# How to compile and extract the packages with classes in a java maven module

Tags: java, maven

I have been trying to create a custom MavenPlugin to extract packages and classes of the current Project.

Here is my code so far:

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}")
MavenProject project;


public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {

    File projectBaseDirectory = project.getBasedir(); 
     //Todo?

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at other plugins?

Comment: I tried loading classes like other people did on Github with an UrlClassLoader, however I only get an ClassNotFoundException then, with some research I found out that it wont work in java 17.